# seach filter inside a parent ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I have an array of objects which is shown below which I called `$scope.parlist`. I already did a research so that I can filter my nested `ng-repeat` whenever the user search for a particular account but I failed

```
[
   {
      bch: "001",
      loan_product: [
         {
            id_code: "ML1",
            asofmonitoring:[{ //asofmonitoring is fixed to have just one object here
                days07:[
                     {
                       loan_no: "ML-XXX-XXX-XXX",
​​​​​​                       name: "John Papa"
                     },
                     {
                       loan_no: "ML-XXX-XXX-XXX",
​​​​​​                       name: "Grace Papa"
                     }
                     ...
                ],
                days08:[
                     {
                       loan_no: "ML-XXX-XXX-XXX",
​​​​​​                       name: "Earl Papa"
                     },
                     {
                       loan_no: "ML-XXX-XXX-XXX",
​​​​​​                       name: "Britney Papa"
                     }
                     ...
                ]
                ...
            }]
         },
         ...
      ]

   }
   ...
]
```

**html**

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="par in parlist" ng-init="outerindex = $index">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="15" style="background-color:rgb(233, 236, 239)">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                 <tbody ng-repeat="prod in par.loan_product" ng-init="innerindex = $index">
                      <tr>
                         <table>
                             <tbody ng-if="prod.asofmonitoring[0].days07.length > 0">
                                  <tr>
                                      <td colspan="2" class="text-left table-warning">
                                         <input type="text" ng-model="q7[innerindex]" class="form-control" placeholder="Search account" aria-label="Search account" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                       </td>

                                    </tr>
                               </tbody>
                               <tbody ng-repeat="days07 in prod.asofmonitoring[0].days07 | filter:q7[innerindex]">
                                     <tr>
                                         <td class="text-center" ng-bind="days07.loan_no">loading...</td>
                                     </tr>
                               </tbody>
                          </table>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
             </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

My problem is I can't make the search filter to work in my `ng-repeat="days07 in prod.asofmonitoring[0].days07` ng-repeat. I already make the other suggestion like putting a `ng-init="outerindex = $index"` and other solution but my `ng-repeat` wont filter. Can anybody help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a scope-related binding issue here.

Both `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` implicitly create new scopes.

You've not included any controller code but I think I'm making a fair assumption that you've not explicitly defining `q7`. Consequently, when `q7` appears inside the `ng-if`, only this scope will be able to access the bound model. The `ng-repeat` is on a sibling element and thus doesn't have the same visibility, which is why nothing happens when you change the text filter model.

Quick solution here would be to explicitly initialise `q7` in your controller to ensure no variable shadowing occurs.

Included a stripped down example below for you:

<sub>**Edit:** Updated to reflect commentary.</sub>

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    // Explicitly declare text filter model so `ng-repeat` does not create shadowed copies
    $scope.q = {};
    $scope.parlist = [
      {
        bch: '001',
        loan_product: [
          {
            id_code: 'ML1',
            asofmonitoring: [
              {
                days07: [
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'John Papa',
                  },
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'Grace Papa',
                  },
                ],
                days08: [
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'Earl Papa',
                  },
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'Britney Papa',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        bch: '002',
        loan_product: [
          {
            id_code: 'ML1',
            asofmonitoring: [
              {
                days07: [
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'John Papa',
                  },
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'Grace Papa',
                  },
                ],
                days08: [
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'Earl Papa',
                  },
                  {
                    loan_no: 'ML-XXX-XXX-XXX',
                    name: 'Britney Papa',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="par in parlist">
    <div ng-repeat="prod in par.loan_product">
      <div ng-if="prod.asofmonitoring[0].days07.length">
        <input type="text" ng-model="q[par.bch][$index]" placeholder="bch: {{par.bch}}">
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="days07 in prod.asofmonitoring[0].days07 | filter:q[par.bch][$index]">
        <div ng-bind="days07.loan_no">loading...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>q = {{ q | json }}</pre>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sir you are right. I fail to declare the `$scope.q7` in my controller so when I tested your suggestion it really works. Thank you so much

Comment: but sir I encounter an error. As you can see there are multiple objects in my `$scope.parlist` array. When I used your code it only filter the first object with the `bch:'001'` but the second object won't filter

Comment: My example isn't intended to be a copy-paste answer to what you're doing—I simply pointed out the conceptual issue with your original snippet. If you want to support multiple text filter models, one solution is to namespace the model used to track the text filters. I've updated my example for your benefit to demonstrate this.